# Are there any open APIs to operate tabs of IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, tabs, bho

I have googled so many times to get some information of SDK to the IE tabs. Recently, I created a BHO plugin for IE, it opens a browser in a new IE window. I want to open it in a new tab page and wish i cound make the tab pages can be switched to each other. I think some open APIs can help me do that, just like the COM interfaces IWebBrowser2, IHTMLDocument2...?
Are there any ones?

Comment: No, there is no explicit tab manager type interface or API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of control are you looking for? If you just want to open a new tab, use Use IWebBrowser2::Navigate, with second parameter (flags) having navOpenInNewTab set.
Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa752133(v=vs.85).aspx.